# Checking Set contains from the list<string> element list

Tags: apex

I have to list of subset of some text and Set of subset of some text and I'm checking to see if set text contains string from the labels but it seems that does not seems to be working

here is my code:

```
public static boolean checkIfExists() {
        Set<String> setEmployee = new Set<String>(); //'my ft','my XYZ','my c2c'
        List<String> labels = Label.EmployeeOptions.split(','); //FT,PT,C2C,...
        for(String s : setEmployee ){  
            if(labels.contains(s)){ 
               return true;   
            }
        } 
       return false;
    }
```

I'm expecting from the above code to return me two element as `true` and one as `false` but my above code does not go to if conditions and return all three elements as `false`

Answer (score 4):

I think that you've confused `String.contains()` and `List.contains()`/`Set.contains()`.

The `contains()` method for Lists and Sets (i.e. collections) is not for searching for substrings inside of a collection. The only time `contains()` will return true is if the entire entry in the collection is matched.

ex.

```java
Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>{'Value A', 'Value B', 'Value C'};

// will print 'false', because Set.contains() doesn't do substring matches
System.debug(mySet.contains('A'));

// will print 'false', because Set.contains() is case-sensitive
System.debug(mySet.contains('value a'));

// will print 'true', because we're giving it an exact match for something contained
//   in the set
System.debug(mySet.contains('Value A'));
```

This behavior is also the same for `List`s.

So you have 2 problems when it comes to the comparison:

1. collection `.contains()` methods can't do substring matches
2. the comparison is going to be case-sensitive

You'll need to address both issues. #1 can be addressed by breaking up your input, similar to how you're breaking up your Label (basically, pull out the substrings *before* doing your `contains()` check). #2 can be addressed with `String.toLowerCase()` (or `String.toUpperCase()`).

A simple nested loop approach could be fine if the length of your input and label are relatively small, but using 2 or 3 non-nested loops isn't that much harder to understand and will scale better.

You also want to use `Set.contains()` if at all possible. `List.contains()` is internally implemented as a loop through the list values, but `Set.contains()` is not. `Set.contains()` is almost guaranteed to run faster.

```java
// Called like checkIfExists(new List<String>{'Value A1', 'Value B2', 'Value C3'});
// Since you want to return multiple results, your return type can't just be
//   simply "Boolean"
public Map<String, Boolean> checkIfExists(List<String> employeeStrings){
    // Set ourselves up to use Set.contains()
    // String.split() gives us a List, but Set has a constructor that can take
    //   a List
    // Also need to lowercase this so that case sensitivity isn't an issue
    Set<String> options = new Set<String>(Label.Options.toLowerCase().split(','));

    // Now we can break up the input into its individual substrings
    // A Map<String, List<String>> will help to later correlate the results
    Map<String, List<String>> inputToSubstrings = new Map<String, List<String>>();

    for(String input :employeeStrings){
        // Again, we need to lowercase some things to address issue #2
        inputToSubstrings.put(input, input.toLowerCase().split(' '));
    }

    Map<String, Boolean> results = new Map<String, Boolean>();

    // Time to do the comparison
    for(String input :inputToSubstrings.keySet()){
        // Set does contain comparison methods that can take Lists, so we don't
        //   _need_ to convert this to a set, but I'm gonna do that anyway.
        // The .clone() here helps ensure that you don't end up modifying the
        //   input to your method here.
        Set<String> employeeSubstringSet = new Set<String>(inputToSubstrings.get(input).clone());

        employeeSubstringSet.retainAll(options);

        // if employeeSubstringSet contained none of the options
        //   e.g. employeeSubstringSet = {'my', 'thing'}
        //     and options = {'ft', 'c2c'}
        // then retainAll() will make the employeeSubstringSet empty.
        // However, if employeeSubstringSet = {'other', 'ft'}, it won't be empty
        results.put(input, !employeeSubstringSet.isEmpty());
    }

    return results;
}
```